# why Subscription on Created is not working on Prisma?

Tags: subscription, prisma

I implemented a simple Prisma server.
My subscriptions work very well with UPDATED and DELETED mutations, but it does not work with CREATED mutations! Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bug from Prisma 1.12. when i updated it to 1.15, it solved!